# Is There a Way to Turn A JPA OneToOne Relationship On and Off for an Entity? Query override in Repository Not Being Followed

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a springboot project with 2 tables with a OneToOne relationship contacts and students, students has primary key studentID and foreign key contactID, contacts has primary key contactID.

```
@Data
@Table(name = "contacts")
public class Contact {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long ContactID;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "contact")
    private Student student;
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long studentID;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer"})
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ContactID", referencedColumnName = "ContactID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Contact contact;
```

I was wondering if there is a way to turn off/ignore the relationship when running a query. Or at least **find out why my query overwrite in the repository isn't being followed.** To get all students with the joined in data from contacts I have mapping set up for /api/Student/AllContacts/ which works as expected.

```
    public List<Student> getStudentsAllWithContacts(){
        return this.studentRepository.findAllWithContacts();
    }
```

which corresponds with the following in the StudentRepository:

```
    @Query("select s from Student s left join fetch s.contact")
    List<Student>  findAllWithContacts();
```

I have another query /api/Student/ that **I would like to only return the data from Students and not join with Contacts**. I even put in a query overwrite and it still does the join implied by the one to one.

In the controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        return this.studentRepository.findAll();
    }
```

In the repository:

```
    @Query("select s from Student s")
    List<Student>  findAll();
```

I thought lazy fetch is not supposed to bring back the lazy properties unless they're asked for. Yet my findAll method still joins with contacts.

[Result of /api/Students/ aka findAll which returns contact when it should be lazy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z4KI.png)

1. Is this not possible with relationships and I just have to delete the relationship and just make 2 separate queries against Students and Contacts from the frontend and use a map and filter function to join the data there?
2. Would I just create a redundant student entity that would not have a relationship with contacts and use that when I only wanted student data?
3. Would this be handled better by creating an entity manager? Like in these tutorials: [https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/vasiliev-jpql.html#:~:text=%20To%20issue%20a%20JPQL%20query%20from%20within,an%20appropriate%20EntityManager%27s%20method%2C%20such%20as...%20More%20](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/vasiliev-jpql.html#:%7E:text=%20To%20issue%20a%20JPQL%20query%20from%20within,an%20appropriate%20EntityManager%27s%20method%2C%20such%20as...%20More%20)

https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/retrieve

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you basically want all students that have, or don't have, contact info?

Your query is explicitly joining `Student` and `Contact`, so of course it's going to join them. You already have the `fetch` as `LAZY`.  That should prevent the fetching of the `Contact` until you access `student.getContact()`.  Just doing something like `@Query("select s from Student s")` should get you just the student entity records.

If you're looking to filter on the existence of a `Contact` relationship without fetching that data, something like the following would work.

I would remove the relationship from `Contact`:

```
@Data
@Table(name = "contacts")
public class Contact {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

Then, write `Student` like such:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer"}) //should this be added
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Contact contact;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "contact_id", nullable = false)
    private Long contactID;
```

Then your query would be:

```
select s from Student s where s.contactId IS NULL
```

```
select s from Student s where s.contactId IS NOT NULL
```

That allows the query to inspect the foreign key without joining against `Contact`.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear enough, I have 2 queries one that is supposed to only return data from the students table findAll "select s from Student s" which still joins with contacts even though it is told explicitly not to in the repository and one that returns data from students joined with contacts findAllWithContacts "select s from Student s left join fetch s.contact". The issue is that both these queries return the same results.